# how to get <nav> to be height:100%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have my side navigation bar (nav) to always reach the bottom of its container (article). I've tried many different ways but nothing seems to be correct. I have a border on the right side of the (nav) and i want that to always stretch to the bottom of the (article) providing a divider from the content text. Some of my page does not scale correctly either and I'm not quite sure where to go. Please help me.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
        height: 100%;
}
body {
 background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 text-size: 100%;
}
html {
 color: white;
}
/* ---------------------- Page Container ---------------------- */
.wrapper {
 background-color: rgb(18, 18, 18);
 width: 90%;
        max-width: 1000px;
        min-width: 600px;
 max-height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 opacity: 0.85;
 display: table;
}
/* ---------------------- End Page Container ---------------------- */
/* ----------------------Header---------------------- */
header {
 width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 1em 0;
 padding: 0;
}
header img,
header h1 {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
header img {
 margin: .3em;
}
header h1 {
        text-shadow: 3px 3px 8px DarkKhaki;
        font-size: 2.7em;
        padding: 0 .05em;
}
header nav {
 border-top: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
 border-bottom: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
 background-color: black;
 opacity:0.7;
 width: 85%;
 max-height: 100%;
 margin: .3em auto 0;
 padding: 1em 0;
 text-align: center;
}
header nav a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: 0;
 transition: color .3s;
 padding: 0 .7em;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
header nav a:hover {
 color: DarkKhaki;
}
/* ---------------------- End Header ---------------------- */
/* ---------------------- Main Content Area ---------------------- */
article {
        border: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
 background-color: black;
 opacity:0.7;
 width: 85%;
 max-height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto 1em;
 padding: 0 0 1em;
 text-align: center;
}
article p {
        padding: 0 .3em;
}
article h1 {
        color: DarkKhaki;
}
/* ---------------------- Project Images ---------------------- */
.projectImage {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: .5em .5em;
}
.projectImage a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: .8em;
}
.projectImage a:hover {
        color: DarkKhaki;
}
.projectImage img {
        width: 110px;
        height: 83px;
        margin-top: .4em;
}
.projectImage img:hover {
        border: 2px solid black;
}
div.projectContent img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 73px;
}
/* ---------------------- End Project Images ---------------------- */
/* ---------------------- Side Navigation for Projects ---------------------- */
article nav {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15%;
        max-width: 15%;
        vertical-align: top;
        border-right: 1px solid gray;
        padding: 0;
        margin: .5em 0;
}
article nav a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: color .2s;
        text-align: left;
        margin: .6em 0 .6em .6em;
}
article nav a:hover {
        color: DarkKhaki;
}
/* ---------------------- End Side Navigation for Projects ---------------------- */
/* ---------------------- Project Content Area ---------------------- */
.projectContent {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 85%;
        max-width: 85%;
        padding: 0 2em;
}
/* ---------------------- End Project Content Area ---------------------- */
/* ---------------------- Resume Page ---------------------- */
aside {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 20%;
}
aside img {
        display: block;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 1em auto;
}
aside img:hover {
        border: 2px solid black;
}
section {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        width: 80%;
        padding: 0 0 0 1em;
}
/* ---------------------- End Resume Page ---------------------- */
/* ---------------------- End Main Content Area ---------------------- */
/* ---------------------- Footer ---------------------- */
footer {
 border-left: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
 border-top: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
 border-right: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
 background-color: black;
 opacity:0.7;
 display: table;
 width: 85%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}
footer p {
 font-size: 0.5em;
 padding: .2em .5em;
}
/* ---------------------- End Footer ---------------------- */
```

```html
<!doctype html />
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Danny Steveson Portfolio</title>
  <link href="_mainStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/titleLogo.png" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <a href="default.html" title="Home Page">
        <img src="images/logo.png" style="width: 106px; height: 106px;" alt="Logo" /></a>
      <h1>Danny Steveson Portfolio</h1>
      <nav>
        <a href="mainWebDesign.html">Web Design</a>
        <a href="mainGameDesign.html">Game Design</a>
        <a href="mainDatabases.html">Databases</a>
        <a href="mainResume.html">Resume</a>
        <a href="mainContact.html">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <article>
      <nav>
        <a href="WDallGolf.html" style="color:DarkKhaki;">Description</a>
      </nav><!--
      --><div class="projectContent">
        <h1>AllGolf.com</h1>
        <p>This text will go past the height of the page causing it to scroll.<br />This text will go past the height of the page causing it to scroll.<br />This text will go past the height of the page causing it to scroll.<br />This text will go past the height of the page causing it to scroll.<br />This text will go past the height of the page causing it to scroll.<br />This text will go past the height of the page causing it to scroll.<br />This text will go past the height of the page causing it to scroll.<br />This text will go past the height of the page causing it to scroll.<br />This text will go past the height of the page causing it to scroll.<br />This text will go past the height of the page causing it to scroll.<br />This text will go past the height of the page causing it to scroll.<br /></p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <footer>
      <p>Created by: Danny Steveson 2015</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgza88pj/3/) does what you want.
What I've done are a couple things:

1. Added `position: relative;` to article
2. Removed `display: inline-block;` from both the content and nav
3. Added `float: right;` to content
4. Added `float: left;` to the nav
5. Added a `:before` element to the article that draws a line next to the nav
6. Added an `:after` element to the article with `clear: both;` (necessary when working with floating elements)

The before element is a hack in a certain way, but certainly does the trick.

Hope this helps

Comment: This works great now. Thank you! It was exactly what I was looking for. Now I just need to research :after elements. Thanks again.

Comment: One problem I have run into though is that if I have a bunch of links in my (nav) and just one or two lines of text in the (content) area, then the links end up going below the (article). In other words the (article) container moves if forced by the (content) but will not move to fit the (nav).

Comment: @dsteveson85 Fixed now :)